# How to use imagemagick to convert an image into text file of pixel hex color then back to an image?

Tags: image, hex, imagemagick, pixel, imagemagick-convert

I can convert an image into pixel coordinate and colors by

```
convert myimage.png txt:
```

---

```
...
7,20: (200,251,251,255)  #C8FBFBFF  srgba(200,251,251,1)
8,20: (200,251,251,255)  #C8FBFBFF  srgba(200,251,251,1)
9,20: (200,251,251,255)  #C8FBFBFF  srgba(200,251,251,1)
10,20: (200,251,251,255)  #C8FBFBFF  srgba(200,251,251,1)
11,20: (200,251,251,255)  #C8FBFBFF  srgba(200,251,251,1)
12,20: (200,251,251,255)  #C8FBFBFF  srgba(200,251,251,1)
13,20: (200,251,251,255)  #C8FBFBFF  srgba(200,251,251,1)
14,20: (0,0,0,255)  #000000FF  black
15,20: (133,81,20,255)  #855114FF  srgba(133,81,20,1)
16,20: (0,0,0,255)  #000000FF  black
...
```

how can I

1. just get the pixel coordinate and hex columns in 1 line without line break in a .txt file? like

   `7,20,#C8FBFBFF 8,20,#C8FBFBFF 9,20,#C8FBFBFF...`
2. convert the text file back to an image file? something like

   `convert pixel.txt image.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in ImageMagick using Awk and other Unix commands as follows:

```
convert myimage.png txt: | tail -n +2  | awk '{print $1 $3}' | tr ":" "," | tr "\n" " "
```

```
The tail skips the first line.
The awk prints the first and third string separated by spaces
The first tr changes : to ,
The second tr changes new lines \n to simple spaces
```

Example:

```
convert lena.png[10x10+0+0] txt: | tail -n +2  | awk '{print $1 $3}' | tr ":" "," | tr "\n" " "
```

```
0,0,#E2897C 1,0,#E08982 2,0,#E18779 3,0,#E48679 4,0,#E38A7D 5,0,#E2877A 6,0,#E18672 7,0,#DF8776 8,0,#DD836E 9,0,#DE8976 0,1,#E2897C 1,1,#E08983 2,1,#E18779 3,1,#E48679 4,1,#E38A7E 5,1,#E2877B 6,1,#E18672 7,1,#DF8777 8,1,#DD836F 9,1,#DE8A76 0,2,#E28A7C 1,2,#E0887F 2,2,#E18778 3,2,#E48679 4,2,#E38979 5,2,#E38577 6,2,#E08572 7,2,#E08573 8,2,#DD836D 9,2,#DE8774 0,3,#E4897A 1,3,#E18672 2,3,#E18676 3,3,#E58470 4,3,#E38571 5,3,#E38675 6,3,#E28169 7,3,#E07E69 8,3,#E0816D 9,3,#E0826C 0,4,#E0826D 1,4,#DF846E 2,4,#E08474 3,4,#E28370 4,4,#E28675 5,4,#E18473 6,4,#E0846C 7,4,#E27F6C 8,4,#E37F6C 9,4,#E0836C 0,5,#DF8268 1,5,#DF856D 2,5,#E2836C 3,5,#E27C6B 4,5,#E1836E 5,5,#E2836E 6,5,#E1836E 7,5,#E2826C 8,5,#E38169 9,5,#E1816E 0,6,#E2836F 1,6,#E2836F 2,6,#E3836C 3,6,#E27F6D 4,6,#E1836E 5,6,#E1846B 6,6,#E38168 7,6,#E2826B 8,6,#E3846C 9,6,#E08370 0,7,#E4846D 1,7,#E2846E 2,7,#E2836C 3,7,#E38469 4,7,#E1826C 5,7,#E18267 6,7,#E3836C 7,7,#E28169 8,7,#E2836C 9,7,#E2816F 0,8,#E38272 1,8,#E2836E 2,8,#E1836D 3,8,#E18069 4,8,#E1826A 5,8,#E38368 6,8,#E2836E 7,8,#E1826B 8,8,#E28066 9,8,#E48169 0,9,#E2826F 1,9,#E0826D 2,9,#E0846F 3,9,#E17F6A 4,9,#E28369 5,9,#E38269 6,9,#E38367 7,9,#E3856D 8,9,#E48467 9,9,#E2856B
```

**ADDITION**

If you want to go back to an image from the list, then put the list into a string variable. Then echo the string and pipe to sed to change ",#" to " #". Then pipe back to convert where you can use -sparse-color voronoi to paint it over a black background image. If you do not have every pixel to fill out the background image, then it will use the voronoi interpolation to fill in.

```
# create string from list of coordinates and hex colors
str=`convert lena.png[10x10+0+0] txt: | tail -n +2  | awk '{print $1 $3}' | tr ":" "," | tr "\n" " "`

# convert string back to image
echo $str | sed 's/,[#]/ \#/g' | convert -size 10x10 xc:black -sparse-color voronoi @- x.png
```

See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#sparse-color

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want for question 1). Would you know how to convert back to an image from the pixel coordinate and hex color text for question 2)?

Comment: See my addition in my answer

Comment: Excellent, that works perfectly. I can't upvote you because of my noob reputation but thank you sir!

Comment: One more questions if you don't mind. Say I have 1000 images in a folder /images, how can i write a script to convert all images to 1000 text files with the pixel coordinate and hex color in /images/files folder?

Comment: Why do you need hex colors with the pixels as opposed to rgb values? If you could use RGB values, you could easily convert to NetPBM PPM text format, which is a common format. That can be done via ImageMagick. See http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html  Otherwise, you would have to write a shell script loop over each directory and file that you want to convert and write the output text files to the desired directory. So you have to script most of that apart from using ImageMagick to convert any given image to your desired text format file.

Comment: RGB or Hex do not matter for my use case. What i really want is a square matrix where each item represents a pixel color of an image. I want this pixel file to be as small in size as possible. For eg a 4x4 matrix like:

W,W,W,W - 0,1 White, 0,2 White ...
W,G,G,W - 1,0 White, 1,1 Green...
G,R,R,G - ... 2,2 Red, 2,3 Gree
W,G,G,W...

I came across imageMagick that could do this job but I realize with pixel coordinate and hex color, the text file size is still too large at 9Kb. Ideally, I want it to be a few bytes. Would you have any other suggestion I should look at?

Comment: No other suggestions.